# How can we disable SSL certificate for https api request. in react-native expo

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, expo-dev-client

> I am getting network request failed with fetch and axios.

Comment: Consider adding what you've tried, your code and any error messages you've seen.  Please also read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For this title is enough to explain what i want.